# Biztalk mapping: sequence of maps at one receive port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I'm stuck with the question: is it possible to assign sequence of maps to one receive port? I understand that I can assign a lot of receive locations and inbound maps to one port and BizTalk will choose first acceptable map according to what message is received. But is it possible to have sequence of maps for one format? Let's say I need to receive EDIFACT. Is it possible to receive it and convert to my internal BizTalk format (let's call it Edifact_to_Core map) and after that make one more internal conversion - let's call it Core_to_Core map? In some reason I can't put this "internal" conversion directly into Edifact_to_Core map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not on a single Receive Port, it will only execute the first one that matches the inbound schema.

If you need two execute two maps you usually execute the first on the Receive Port and another on the send port.

If you require more maps to be executed than that, you either need to have
them in an Orchestration, or if you want to have a messaging only solution, use a Loop Back Adapter or the BRE Pipeline Framework to run multiple maps.